# Let $s_i=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$ diverge, does $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{a_i}{s_i^2}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, contest-math

Let $a_1,a_2\dots$ be a sequence of positive reals such that $s_n=a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$ diverges.

Does it follow that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{a_i}{s_i^2}$ converges? I am really stumped at this problem. I tried finding counterexamples like $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log n}$ and got some series which I was unsure whether they diverged or not. But at then every example I have tried converges. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/convergence-of-sum-fraca-ns-n-1-epsilon-where-s-n-sum-i-1?rq=1

Comment: The answer is the link above is remarkable simple for the particular case considered here. From $a_n^2 = a_n(S_n - S_{n-1}) \geq 0$ it follows that $$\frac{a_n}{S_{n}^2} \leq \frac{1}{S_{n-1}}-\frac{1}{S_n} \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{S_n^2} \leq \frac{2}{a_1}$$