# Is following series convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If     $$ \sum  x_n$$  is divergent where $x_n$'s  are non negative. For $p \geq 1$, is it true that
$$ \sum \frac{x_n}{(x_1 + \cdots +x_n)^p} $$  is convergent?

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55670/convergence-of-sum-fraca-ns-n-1-epsilon-where-s-n-sum-i-1?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

We assume that $x_n>0$, for all $n$. Otherwise we delete all the zero terms and the sum does not change.

For $p=1$ it is not, in general, true. Take for example $x_n=1$, for all $n$, and then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{x_1+\cdots+x_n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty.
$$

Let $p>1$ and set $s_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{x_k}{(x_1+\cdots+x_k)^p}=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{s_k-s_{k-1}}{s^p_k}
\le\sum_{k=2}^n\int_{s_{k-1}}^{s_k}\frac{dx}{x^p}=\int_{s_1}^{s_n}\frac{dx}{x^p}<\int_{s_1}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^p}=\frac{s_1^{1-p}}{p-1}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{(x_1+\cdots+n_k)^p}\le \frac{x_1}{x_1^p}+\frac{s_1^{1-p}}{p-1}.
$$